# Poner width a ciertos inputs diferente habiendo una clase "input" general aplica para todos

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, dom

Buen dia, tengo la siguiente clase que se aplica para todos los inputs del DOM

```
input
{
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: .5s ease;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}
input:hover
{
  padding-left: 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(90,90,90,0.2) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(90,90,90,0.2) inset;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
input:focus
{
  padding-left: 25px;
  /*background: rgba(255,253,232,1);*/
}
```

Quisiera ponerle a unos cuantos inputs un ancho de 50px ya que se digitará valores cortos en ellos, que queden como los de la clase solo que no sea tan ancho, intenté ponerle el atributo witdh="50" pensando que tendría preferencia pero no lo toma, es como si la clase mencionada tuviera mas prevalencia sobre ese atributo, es posible que a esos cuantos inputs, me tome todo lo de la clase pero con un width de 50px?

Comment: ¿Dichos inputs siguen alguna regla?, por ejemplo ¿son los pares los impares?, ¿algún indicio de patrón por el cual elegirlos?

Comment: Existe una jerarquía dentro de `CSS`, es decir, dependiendo de donde declares el estilo, tendrá mayor o menor importancia respecto a otros. Mejor puedes mirarlo por aquí, puede que aclare tu pregunta: https://www.elmaquetadorweb.com/2018/05/jerarquia-css-como-evitar-el-uso-de.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente necesitas o bien asignarles una clase más específica o bien añadir otra regla con un selector que indique a qué `inputs` te refieres. Por ejemplo:

```
input.anchofijo { width: 50px }
```

Y en el HTML pondrías:

```
< input class="anchofijo" />
```

en cada elemento que quieras que se comporte así.

Por otra parte también puedes investigar los diferentes selectores CSS: hay selectores que te permiten marcar el primer elemento de cada tipo, los elementos que están dentro de otro, etc. Y esto es una mejor práctica que utilizar clases, aunque te pueda resultar más sencillo lo primero para empezar.

Comment: Excelente! si he eso leido, por ahora esto me funciona, muy amable!